# How is it possible to request an instance of model in Rails (when scaffolding used)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, scaffolding

Is it possible to get an object via AJAX function in Rails application or should I write a common AJAX request and a custom handler for that? Maybe there is a .js AJAX-based function `get(object.id)`.

I think it is a typical problem that many developers are familiar with, however it is not an easy task to find a suitable search query in google (I always get only totally unrelated results)

The **context of the question** is following: I have an index.html generated via rails scaffold, when I want to create a new object it navigates to a new page with a form for a new object. I would like to make it on the same page via frontend templates, just adding the form as a new table row. The order of creation of the object is not so important, however it would be nice to create the object after the form is filled and the submited, not when the form is appended to the table.

I don't want to refresh the whole page to get all the objects in the table (is a very expensive operation due to the redundancy), but rather to just update the new items in the table.

Comment: can you please share your view files and controller ? I assume what you need ujs

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a table in your index.html.erb file

```
<table class="my-table">
<tbody class="table-body">
   <% @collection.each do |object| %>
     <tr>
       <td><input value="<%= object.attribute1 %>" /></td>
       ...
     </tr>
   <% end %>
</tbody>
```

you need `remote: true` for your new form

```
<%= form_tag(@resource, remote: true) do %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

you also need `new.js.erb` (assuming new action can respond_to :js)

`$(".my-table > tbody:last").append('<%= j render(@resouce) %>');`

Comment: and how I can call it from the front end? I mean not at load time, but rather say - just from the js console, just to test: I create a new instance using `rails console` and I would like to load it from js console with something like: `RailsHelpJS.getInstance('MyClass', 'new_instance_id')` is it possible?

Comment: You can use jQuery load funcion `$(".my-table > tbody:last").load(show_resource_path);` is that what you trying ?